# How do I make sublimerepl close the instance of Python it created when I close the sublimerepl tab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I'm running Python 3.6 and Sublime Text 3. I tend to use Sublimerepl to quickly run my code and verify that everything works whenever I make a few changes and close the tab right afterwords. This does mean that when I exit Sublime, I also need to go into Task Manager and end > 10 instances of python ususally. Is there a way to make closing the sublimerepl tab also close the instance of Python that it created?

Comment: Hmm quick question, after a run is finished do you see something like ***Repl Closed*** at the bottom of the tab?

Comment: No. I can still input commands afterwards, which is fine. In fact, a better would have been how to make it say Repl Closed so I can just do it manually.

Comment: Hi @knockupwood did the below answer help solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it did. Thnks @flacle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably means that the program is still running in the background, one way to end the instance is to right-click somewhere on the open tab that is running the Python instance and select **Kill** from the contextual menu, instead of going to the Task Manager.